# Prove that the integer sequence $a_n$ defined as $2^{n+1} -3 = a_n \mod 1000$ has a period of 100.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I have noticed a pattern when generating this sequence. $a_1=1$; but after that I get 100 numbers that then keep repeating ($5,13,29,\ldots,373,749,501$). Obviously running simulations on a computer is not proof that this sequence has a period of 100. Is there a way to prove this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, since you are only interested in periodicity, you can safely ignore the $-3$ term.

And then, according to the [Chinese Remainder Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_remainder_theorem), you can look separately at the sequence $b_{n} = 2^{n}$ modulo $8$ and modulo $125$.

Modulo $8$ the sequence becomes of course constant $0$ at $n = 3$. This explains why the first few terms do not repeat.

So let us look at it modulo $125$. Since $2$ is invertible modulo $125$, it will have a period which divides [$\varphi(125) = \varphi(5^{3}) = 5^{3} - 5^{2} = 100$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_totient_function). To prove that the period is indeed $100$, and not a proper divisor of it, it suffices to check that
$$
2^{100/2} \equiv 124 \pmod{125},
\qquad
2^{100/5} \equiv 76 \pmod{125}.
$$

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply! I can follow you up to the first three paragraphs. Being a novice in number theory I cannot understand the term "2 is invertible modulo 125". Also the last sentence is not clear to me I am afraid.

Comment: As to your first question, please look up [the group of integers which are invertible modulo a given integer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_multiplicative_inverse). As to your second question, the [order of an element of a finite group has to divide the order of the group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_(group_theory)#Order_and_structure). So if the order is not $100$, it has to be a proper divisor of $100$, and then a divisor of either $100/2$ or $100/5$.

Comment: Many thanks for your answers. I have to explain this to high school students, hence the many questions...